# ascending/descending table based on select options using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement sorting of the table using select options(names/type/doc/date) and click on the other select options which include ascending and descending the table should display the sorting result. Please help. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. Below is, my code which has a radio button used for descending/ascending.

```js
(function($) {
  const
    cellValue = (row, index) => index !== -1 ? $(row).children('td').eq(index).text() : 0,
    compareCells = (index, options) =>
      (rowA, rowB) => {
        const colOpts = options[index] || {};
        let
          a = cellValue(rowA, index),
          b = cellValue(rowB, index);
        if (colOpts.dateFormat) {
          a = moment(a, colOpts.dateFormat).valueOf(),
          b = moment(b, colOpts.dateFormat).valueOf()
        }
        return $.isNumeric(a) && $.isNumeric(b) ? a - b : a.toString().localeCompare(b);
      };
  Object.assign($.fn, {
    scanSelectOptionData: function() {
      return [...this.get(0).options].reduce((acc, option, index) => {
        const colOpts = {};
        if (option.dataset.dateFormat) {
          colOpts.dateFormat = option.dataset.dateFormat;
        }
        return { ...acc, [option.value]: colOpts };
      });
    },
    sortTable: function(columnIndex, opts, reverse) {
      let rows = this.find('tbody tr').toArray().sort(compareCells(columnIndex, opts));
      return this.append(reverse ? rows.reverse() : rows);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  const
    $table = $('#myTable'),
    $select = $('#nameselect > select'),
    $radio = $('input[name="sort-direction"]');

  const sortTable = () => {
    const
      columnIndex = parseInt($select.val(), 10),
      opts = $select.scanSelectOptionData(),
      reverse = $('input[name="sort-direction"]:checked').val() === 'DESC';
    $table.sortTable(columnIndex, opts, reverse);
  };

  $select.on('change', sortTable);
  $radio.on('change', sortTable);
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: thin solid grey;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

th, td {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#nameselect, .sort-direction-radio {
  display: inline-flex;
}

#nameselect > select {
  min-width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div id="nameselect">
  <select required>
    <option value="-1">select</option>
    <option value="0">Names</option>
    <option value="1">Type</option>
    <option value="2">Doc</option>
    <option value="3" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY">Date</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="selectlogic" style="display:inline-flex">
  <select required>
    <option>select</option>
    <option value="0">Ascending</option>
    <option value="1">Descending</option>
    
  </select>
</div>

<div class="sort-direction-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="sort-direction" value="ASC" checked />ASC
  <input type="radio" name="sort-direction" value="DESC" />DESC
</div>

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr id="table-header">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Doc</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="">
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>text1</td>
      <td>word</td>
      <td>1/1/21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" data-type="John">
      <td>John</td>
      <td>text2</td>
      <td>Excel</td>
      <td>31/1/21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" data-type="Martin">
      <td>Martin</td>
      <td>text3</td>
      <td>pdf</td>
      <td>21/2/21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" data-type="Rozi">
      <td>Rozi</td>
      <td>text4</td>
      <td>powepoint</td>
      <td>5/10/20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: btw what is the `moment` function supposed to do? it works for everything except date

Comment: @TheBombSquad. I don't want asc/des for a date.. for other columns it should work. The date column is exceptional only for reference I have added it